# How to see files of a particular tag in org-roam?

Tags: org-mode, org-roam

Before I installed org-roam I saw a screenshot or a video somewhere in which the tags of an org-roam note looked like links. I was under the impression that org-roam allows you to see all notes of a particular tag.

I added a tag to my test note, but I don't see a way to see all notes with that tag. I also could not find any hints on that in the [org-roam User Guide](https://www.orgroam.com/manual/index.html#SEC_Contents).

How can I see a list of all notes with a particular tag (ideally as a list of links so that I can click on a note to navigate to it)?

Comment: do you mean something like listing all notes linked to a tag in a sidebuffer or window? Because I am probably looking for something similar after having watched 'How to Use Roam to Outline a New Article in Under 20 Minutes' by Nat Eliason (which is also linked in one of the org-roam blog posts).

Answer (score 4):

You can search by tag by running `org-roam-find-file`. The tags will be displayed in brackets next to the titles of the files.

To see a list of files as you type, set `org-roam-completion-system` to `'ido`.

```
(setq org-roam-completion-system 'ido)
```

Alternatively,

- install Ivy and enable `ivy-mode`, or
- install Helm and enable `helm-mode`.

Ido, Ivy, and Helm are all completion systems.

#### Additional reading about completion systems

- See [Mastering Emacs - Introduction to Ido Mode](https://masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-to-ido-mode) for an (in-depth) introduction to Ido as a completion system. Some excerpts:

  - A description of builtin "completing-read", the prompt that you're seeing:

  > [...] if you were to search for the buffer “*Customize Group: Foobar*” without Ido you’d have to contort your fingers and type the *, then TAB (and hope it completes) and if not, type in some more; then rinse and repeat.

  - Describing Ido:

  > With Ido you’d type a few characters until you find the match, or until you narrow down your list of matches to a manageable subset, and then press RET. Even better, with fuzzy matching you can find things even more efficiently. So the above buffer name could be found by typing “cgf” – c for Customize, g for Group and f for Foobar.
- See [Helm Wiki#General concept](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#general-concept) for what Helm is in addition to just being a vertical Ido.

  > People often think helm is just something like ido but displaying completion in a vertical layout instead of an horizontal one, it is not, helm is much more powerful than that.
- See [Ivy Manual#Introduction](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#introduction)

  > Ivy is for quick and easy selection from a list. When Emacs prompts for a string from a list of several possible choices, Ivy springs into action to assist in narrowing and picking the right string from a vast number of choices.

Comment: When I enter `M-x org-roam-find-file` I get a prompt asking me for a file name.

Comment: @Mentiflectax You can also enter tags, try typing the tag you want.

Comment: It does not work. If I type in at the file prompt, it creates a new capture file with the text I entered as the title (`#+TITLE`).

Comment: Are you using helm?

Comment: No, I am not using helm.

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70560/12336

Answer (score 2):

This extends [@Lore's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77263) for an arbitrary tag.

```
(defun my/org-roam-node-has-tag (node tag)
  "Filter function to check if the given NODE has the specified TAG."
  (member tag (org-roam-node-tags node)))

(defun my/org-roam-node-find-by-tag ()
  "Find and open an Org-roam node based on a specified tag."
  (interactive)
  (let ((tag (read-string "Enter tag: ")))
    (org-roam-node-find nil nil (lambda (node) (my/org-roam-node-has-tag node tag)))))
```

Usage:

`M-x my/org-roam-node-find-by-tag RET project RET <tab>`

will list possible completions.

***-qux.org**

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       e4fa1ce7-915d-4f41-9858-23d8df0bf176
:END:
#+title: qux
#+filetags:project
```

**Snapshots:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

`M-x org-roam-diagnostics`

> Copy info below this line into issue:
>
> - Emacs: GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.36, cairo version 1.17.6)  of 2023-01-02
> - Framework:
> - Org: Org mode version 9.5.5 (release_9.5.5 @ /usr/share/emacs/28.2/lisp/org/)
> - Org-roam: 2.2.2- sqlite-connector: sqlite

**Some perspective welcomed on these items:**

1. One should be able to replicate the full tags matching functionality of `org-tags-view`. Has anyone seen it?
2. In relation with [@JamesRettie's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61344) `C-h f org-roam-find-file` does not match anything in my case
3. There must be a reason systemcrafters uses`file+head` for capture templates, but I use just `file`:

```
    (org-roam-capture-templates
     '(("d" "default" plain
    "#+title: ${title}\n#+filetags:%^{tags}\n%?"
    :if-new (file "%<%Y%m%d%H%M%S>-${slug}.org")
    :unnarrowed t)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the node search to only display nodes with a specific tag, `org-roam-node-find` accepts a filter function as its third argument. This is covered incidentally in a [video by System Crafters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUkuyW6hr18). The code from that video is:

```
(defun my/org-roam-filter-by-tag (tag-name)
    (lambda (node)
        (member tag-name (org-roam-node-tags node))))

(defun my/org-roam-find-project ()
    (interactive)
    ;; Select a project file to open, creating it if necessary
    (org-roam-node-find nil nil
        (my/org-roam-filter-by-tag "Project")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The hack to enter `org-roam` tags linking them to empty files has been deprecated in `org-roam` since the addition of `#+ROAM_TAGS`

Instead, try adding a line such as `#+ROAM_TAGS: tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4` to an org-file to your `org-roam-directory`.

Then, rebuild the cache using `M-x` and `org-roam-db-build-cache`. Now your completion system (ido, helm etc.) will be able to display the tags inside brackets when using `org-roam-find-file`.