# Tag column (for +FILETAG) in org-roam node list is is gone

Tags: org-roam

In the past when I searched for org-roam nodes via `C-c n f` I could saw the `+FILETAGS` in the right column of the search results. Here is an example where you can see two entries with `#Bib` tag.

[image]

After an update of all packages via `M-x list-packages` + `U` + `x` the tag column is gone. In which package should I look into to find the correct setting/variable or open a ticket for it. Maybe the default value of variable changed after the update?

I am not sure which component is responsible for such search results. Is it `ivy`, `ivy-rich` or `counsel`. I am using all of them in my `init.el`.

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; === Package setup ===
(require 'package)

(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
             ;("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/")
             ("elpa" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
;; Initializes the package infrastructure
(package-initialize)

;; === use-package ==
;; use-package to simplify the config file
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)
(setq use-package-always-ensure 't)

;; === Improved search field
; M-o opens "context menu" of a search item
(use-package ivy
  :diminish
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1)
  (setq ivy-use-selectable-prompt t)
  )

;; === COUNSEL
; add some extra infos to some minibuffers
; e.g. ivy-rich need it
(use-package counsel
  :bind (("M-x" . counsel-M-x)
     ("C-x b" . counsel-switch-buffer)  ; counsel-ibuffer
     ("C-x C-f" . counsel-find-file)))

;; === Add docstring column to function search results
(use-package ivy-rich
  :init
  (ivy-rich-mode 1))

(use-package org)

(use-package org-roam
  :init  ; is called before the package is loaded
  (setq org-roam-v2-ack t)  ; do not show migration warning after startup
  :custom
  (org-roam-directory "~/tab-cloud/my.org-roam")
  :bind (("C-c n f" . org-roam-node-find)
     )
  :config
  (org-roam-db-autosync-mode)
  )
```

The used Emacs is

`GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0)  of 2021-03-28, modified by Debian`

The other packages

- `counsel` :: 20211230.1909 (melpa)
- `ivy` :: 20211231.1730 (melpa)
- `ivy-rich` :: 20210409.931 (melpa)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it seems like `org-roam-node-display-template` was changed to `"${title}"`, you can customize it to the old default value:

```
(setq org-roam-node-display-template
      (concat "${title:*} " (propertize "${tags:10}" 'face 'org-tag)))
```